# How to create a function which auto populate / fills, the text fields of a grid on a button click event. (Using react function components.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

*I need to auto populate/fill below text fields when a user clicks the "Add Data"  button, to do this I have to use react functional components not class components.*

Please help me I'm quiet new to using React JS. Thank you.

```
const grid = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState(
 {
   Name:'',
   Age:'',
   Address:'',
   Gender:''
   )
 const showResults = (e) =>{
 setData(
  {
  Name:'John',
  Age:'21',
  Address:'New York',
  Gender:'Male'
 })}

return(
<SolutionContainer>
 <DemoContainer>
  <Grid>

   <Grid item xs={12}>
    <TextField
     varient="outlined"
     label="Name"
     name="Name"
    />
   </Grid>

  <Grid>
   <Grid item xs={12}>
    <TextField
     varient="outlined"
     label="Age"
     name="Age"
    />
   </Grid>    

  <Grid>
   <Grid item xs={12}>
    <TextField
     varient="outlined"
     label="Address"
     name="Address"
    />
   </Grid>


  <Grid>
   <Grid item xs={12}>
    <TextField
     varient="outlined"
     label="Gender"
     name="Gender"
    />
   </Grid>



   <Grid item xs={12}>
    <StyledButton
      varient = "outlined"
      color = "Blue"
      onClick = {showResults}
     >
     Add Data
    </StyledButton>
   </Grid>

  </Grid>
 </DemoContainer>
</SolutionContainer>
)
}
```

Comment: Hey @wrthnayaka, you have not used the `data` state anywhere in your JSX code. Include the state in JSX part and it will work.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add it to my code? I'm quiet struggling with it.

Comment: I have made some changes in your code, you can refer here https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-swirles-2ip83?file=/src/App.js.